# Set up alert for Nimbus in Linux Server

Tags: linux, notifications, monitoring, apache-zookeeper, nimbus

I have a server where Nimbus/Supervisor/Zookeeper is continuously running. I want to get E-Mail Notification whenever any of them is not running or if server is down due to any reason. What script should I write? I know the mail and cron part, Just need some hint on the Nimbus Checking part? A very lame way that i used is that I did

```
`ps -ef | grep Nimbus`
```

And I checked what it returns. But I believe it won't work when the server itself is down. I didn't check because it is a running server and I don't want to mess with it. So, Do I have to use any other application?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way might be to use `wait`. Not sure whether it'll be possible for your app or not. But possible use might be like below :

```
        wait `processname`
```

Return indicates the process has exited.